# How to put all product attributes below description without shortcode Woocommerce

Tags: function, woocommerce, attributes

currently I've used this code and put shortcode and id in every product post.

```
add_shortcode("product_attributes", "display_product_attributes");
function display_product_attributes( $atts ) {

    // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id'    => ''
        ),
        $atts, 'product_attributes'
    );

    if( ! ( isset($atts['id']) && $atts['id'] > 0 ) ) return;

    $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    ob_start();

    do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Can someone share new code that I don't need to use shortcode and it's will automaticly show additional product information in every below product description post?

Example like picture below

[combine description and additional information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUyVz.png)

Comment: The answer is overriding `single-product/tabs/description.php` woocommerce template via your theme (copying the template to your theme as explained in [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)), then editing it adding to it some code from `single-product/product-attributes.php` in it.

Comment: okay thank you @LoicTheAztec , I will try to create my own template

Comment: You don't need to create your own template, you need to change an existing one…